# Running npm install does not produce lock file

Tags: npm, npm-install

When running `npm install`, when will it produce a `package-lock.json` file and when will it not?

This is the version of npm that I am using:

```
$ npm --version
3.10.10
```

And this a simple `package.josn` that I am testing with:

```
$ cat package.json 
{
  "name": "invoices_svc",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@.../TotalInvoiceDemoApp.git"
  },
  "description": "..."
}
```

For some reason, I don't see a `package-lock.json` that is created after running `npm install`.

I also tried building a docker image with this, where I notice the warning:

> npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.

```
...
Step 4/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in f4c48bbcc52a
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
...
```

There may be some obvious configuration that I missed in my local dev environment? Why it won't produce the lock file locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lock-file was introduced in npm version 5.0.0, you need to update npm to generate lock files